# Class not found when running on a node

Tags: java, cloudbees

I've configured a slave to run on my machine, the slave is connected and recognized by Jenkins.

I've configured my project to use that specific slave and I can see that it kicks into action when a job needs to be done.

After a while I receive the following error:

```
[Android Tunneling] $ /opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -cp maven3-agent.jar:/opt/maven/apache-      maven-3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4 /home/efi/Documents/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar maven3-interceptor.jar 34176
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
```

When running this command locally via terminal I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.main(Maven3Main.java:128)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.main(Maven3Main.java:63)
```

Any idea what might be the problem ?

Comment: I could suggests that this should be the firewall problem

Answer (score 0):

Command line is looking for maven to be installed on /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.0.4 (default location for cloudbees slaves). If your local setup don't match this, you need to override tools location for this custom slave

Comment: Appreciate your response, after reinstalling the server it seems that things are working again.